# Remove the list of dividers in the first row of the title slide (beamer)

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, sections-paragraphs

I would like to remove the list of the sections that shows up at the top of the title slide, but I would like to keep it in the remaining slides. I know it's     possible to do it, but I don't know how

```
\documentclass[10pt,english,usenames dvipsnames]{beamer}

\newcommand\makebeamertitle{\frame{\maketitle}}%
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \let\origtableofcontents=\tableofcontents
\def\tableofcontents{\@ifnextchar[{\origtableofcontents}    {\gobbletableofcontents}}
    \def\gobbletableofcontents#1{\origtableofcontents}
}

\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\date{\today}
\usepackage[draft]{pgf}
\usepackage{listings}

\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\title{Title}

\author[Author]{name}

\makebeamertitle

\AtBeginSubsection[]{%
  \frame<beamer>{ 
    \frametitle{Outline}   
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection] 
}
}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}{Slide 1}
In this section...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If I comment out `\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}` then I remove the list from all the slides, while I want to remove it only from the first slide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the headline (and the - in your example non-existing - footline) by using the `plain` frame option.

Some other comments:

- the correct way to pass options to xcolor in beamer is to use `xcolor={usenames,dvipsnames}` as class option. All you attempts to do this after the document class will have no effect
- no need to load the `pgf` package, beamer does this for you.
- the `\makeatother` does not have any effect at this position
- if you put `\title{Title} \author[Author]{name}` before `\begin{document}` it will be included in the meta data of the `.pdf`.

---

```
\documentclass[10pt,english,xcolor={usenames,dvipsnames}]{beamer}

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \let\origtableofcontents=\tableofcontents
\def\tableofcontents{\@ifnextchar[{\origtableofcontents}    {\gobbletableofcontents}}
    \def\gobbletableofcontents#1{\origtableofcontents}
}

%\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}
%\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\date{\today}
%\usepackage[draft]{pgf}
\usepackage{listings}

\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}

%\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}

\title{Title}

\author[Author]{name}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
  \maketitle
\end{frame}

\AtBeginSubsection[]{%
  \frame<beamer>{ 
    \frametitle{Outline}   
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection] 
}
}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}{Slide 1}
In this section...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```